# convert existing numeric cells to text

Tags: openoffice-calc

I've got a .xls file with a column of zip codes.

Since they are all 5 digit numbers, Open Office Calc is treating them as numbers.  I want it to treat them as text.

I know I can do it by prepending an apostrophe to all the numeric fields.  But I've got a couple dozen spreadsheets with a couple thousand zip codes.

I've tried selecting the column and doing Format - Cells - picking the Number tab and selecting Text.  But that doesn't work and the Format Code is @ instead of '

Is there a way to select a column of numeric data and automatically add a ' to the beginning of each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using VBA in a macro, which would be straightforward. Alternatively you can make a [formula](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/formula_begin.htm) using BAHTTEXT (under text) which converts numbers to text. If that doesn't work you can use CONCATENATE and have a column of all apostrophes, and just join those two columns. Then just drag down the formula and you will have a new column of text.